# Cannot debug simple ksh programme

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I wrote this sample KornShell (ksh) code but it is getting bad substitution error during the if clause.

```
while ((i < $halflen))
do
 if [[${strtochk:i:i}==${strtochk:j:j}]];then
       i++
       j--
 else
  ispalindrome = false
 fi
done
```

Please help.

NB: I am using `ksh88`, not `ksh93`.

Comment: Don't know `strtochk`, any definition ?

Comment: What is the bad substitution error?

Comment: Note: the question [Bad substitution error in `ksh`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962928/bad-substitution-error-in-ksh) is a duplicate of this — and the comments there mentioned the use of `ksh88` instead of `ksh93`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shell syntax is very whitespace sensitive:

- `[[` is acually the name of a command, it's not just syntax, so there must be a space following it.
- The last argument of `[[` must be `]]`, so it needs to be preceded by a space.
- `[[` works differently depending on the number of arguments it receives, so you want to have spaces around `==`
- In a variable assignment, you must not have spaces around `=`.

Tips:

- once you figure out it's not a palindrome, `break` out of the while loop
- you are probably checking character by character, so you want `${strtochk:i:1}`
- `i++` and `j--` are arithmetic expressions, not commands, so you need the double parentheses.
- are you starting with `i=0` and `j=$((${#strtochk} - 1))`?

```
while ((i < halflen))
do
    if [[ ${strtochk:i:1} == ${strtochk:j:1} ]];then
        ((i++))
        ((j--))
    else
        ispalindrome=false
        break
    fi
done
```

Check if your system has [`rev`](http://man.cx/rev), then you can simply do:

```
if [[ $strtochk == $( rev <<< "$strtochk" ) ]]; then
    echo "'$strtochk' is a palindrome"
fi
```

---

```
function is_palindrome {
     typeset strtochk=$1
     typeset -i i=1 j=${#strtochk}
     typeset -i half=$(( j%2 == 1 ? j/2+1 : j/2 ))
     typeset left right

     for (( ; i <= half; i++, j-- )); do
         left=$( expr substr "$strtochk" $i 1 )
         right=$( expr substr "$strtochk" $j 1 )
         [[ $left == $right ]] || return 1
     done
     return 0
}

if is_palindrome "abc d cba"; then
    echo is a palindrome
fi
```

Comment: Hi. I am using ksh 88. Thus  [[ ${strtochk:i:1} == ${strtochk:j:1} ]] does not work. Also, rev is also not supported. Any other alternatives

Comment: You may need to fall back on the [`expr`](http://man.cx/expr) command and its substr subcommand

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to show how. I am really stuck here

Comment: @Programmer, there you go

Answer (score 1):

You are using `ksh88` but the code you tried is using `ksh93` feature missing for the 88 version.

You need to replace

```
if [[${strtochk:i:i}==${strtochk:j:j}]];then
```

with these portable lines:

```
if [ "$(printf "%s" "$strtochk" | cut -c $i)" =
     "$(printf "%s" "$strtochk" | cut -c $j)" ]; then
```

and the incorrect:

```
i++
j--
```

with:

```
i=$((i+1))
j=$((j-1))
```