# Bad substitution error in ksh

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh, substitution

The following KornShell (ksh) script should check if the string is a palindrome.  I am using `ksh88`, not `ksh93`.

```
#!/bin/ksh
strtochk="naman"
ispalindrome="true"
len=${#strtochk}
i=0
j=$((${#strtochk} - 1))
halflen=$len/2
print $halflen
while ((i < $halflen))
do
 if [[ ${strtochk:i:1} == ${strtochk:j:1} ]];then
       (i++)
       (j--)
 else
  ispalindrome="false"
  break
 fi
done

print  ispalindrome
```

But I am getting bad substitution error at the following line : `if [[ ${strtochk:i:1} == ${strtochk:j:1} ]];then`

Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The substring syntax in `${strtochk:i:1}` and `${strtochk:j:1}` is not available in ksh88.  Either upgrade to ksh93, or use another language like awk or bash.

Comment: Please explain how to use awk. That was the whole point of me mentioening that I am using ksh 88

Comment: You can use: `echo ${strtochk} | cut -c${i}-2` for ksh88 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace your test with this portable line:

```
if [ "$(printf "%s" "$strtochk" | cut -c $i)" =
     "$(printf "%s" "$strtochk" | cut -c $j)" ]; then
```

You also need to replace the dubious

```
halflen=$len/2
```

with

```
halflen=$((len/2))
```

and the ksh93/bash syntax:

```
$((i++))
$((j--))
```

with this ksh88 one:

```
i=$((i+1))
j=$((j-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this KornShell (ksh) script for checking if an input string is a palindrome.

**isPalindrome.ksh**

```
#!/bin/ksh 

#-----------
#---Main----
#-----------
echo "Starting: ${PWD}/${0} with Input Parameters: {1: ${1} {2: ${2} {3: ${3}"
echo Enter the string
read s
echo $s > temp
rvs="$(rev temp)"
if [ $s = $rvs ]; then
    echo "$s is a palindrome"
else
    echo "$s is not a palindrome"
fi  
echo "Exiting: ${PWD}/${0}"
```